# Constructor on type 'System.String' not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm doing a UWP in C# using SQLite for UWP (3.18.0.0) and SQLite.Net-PCL.

The code is here:

```
        // open a database
        DatabasePath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DBpath);
        m_sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DatabasePath);

        // display its path
        Debug.WriteLine(m_sqlConnection.DatabasePath);

        // query data from a table
        // something goes wrong, an exception is thrown
        List<string> result = m_sqlConnection.Query<string>("select * from tb11;");

        foreach (var each in result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(each);
        }
```

There is no error during the compile time, but it throws an exception at the "Query" method.

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Constructor on type 'System.String' not found.'
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to solve the problem?

Thanks for your patience. _(:з」∠)_

Comment: Does that table only have one column?  If not you should select the column you want in the list instead of all columns.

Comment: When you "select * from tb11", the returned value usually would not be a list of `string`. That's where your problem is. To solve the problem, we need know what's your "tbl1" is. Or like @juharr said, you should only select one column and it's data type should be `string`.

Comment: There are 2 columns in the simple table, like this:
-------------------
 one       two
-------------------
'hello'      10
'world'     20
-------------------
@juharr But when I execute 
`List<string> result = sql.Query<string>("select one from tb11;")`,
I got the same exception. @JayZuo-MSFT

Comment: If you still have this problem, then please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue. So that we can help you furtherö